# I cannot retrieve the data even though it is stored in the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mern, data-retrieval

I created a project with mern stack, and when I try to comment on the post from the client, the comment does not appear, even though it shows me that the comment was completed successfully, and the comment is saved in the database.

In one of my attempts, I was able to make comments print on the console, but I cannot make them appear on the page

Comments should appear in the post page

PostPage.jsx:

```
    const { pid } = useParams();

  const currentPost = posts[0];
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPost = async () => {
      setPosts([]);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/posts/${pid}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        if(data.error) {
          showToast("Error", data.error, "error");
          return;
        }
        setPosts([data]);
      } catch (error) {
        showToast("Error", error.message, "error");
      }
    }
    getPost();
  }, [pid, setPosts, showToast]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getComment = async () => {
      setComments([]);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/comments/${pid}/comments`);
        const data = await res.json();
        if(data.error) {
          showToast("Error", data.error, "error");
          return;
        }
        console.log([data])
        setComments([data]);
      } catch (error) {
        showToast("Error", error.message, "error");
      }
    }
    getComment();
  }, [pid, setComments, showToast]);

return (
  ...page codes

  <Flex>
  
{comments?.length >= 0 && comments?.map((comment) => {
  return <Comment 
  key={comment?._id} 
  comment={comment} 
  lastComment={comment?._id === comments[comments?.length - 1]._id}
  />
})}
</Flex>

)
```

comment.jsx:

```
import { Avatar, Divider, Flex, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";


const Comment = ({ comment, lastComment }) => {
  return (
    <>
    <Flex gap={4} py={2} my={2} w={"full"}>
        <Avatar src={comment.userProfilePic} size={"sm"}/>
        <Flex gap={1} w={"full"} flexDirection={"column"}>
            <Flex w={"full"} justifyContent={"space-between"} alignItems={"center"}>
                <Text fontSize={"sm"} fontWeight={"bold"}>
                    {comment.username}
                </Text>
                
            </Flex>
            <Text>{comment.comment}</Text>
        </Flex>
    </Flex>
    {!lastComment ? <Divider /> : null}
    </>
  )
}

export default Comment
```

commentController.js

```
const getComments = async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params;
        try {
            if(id) {
            const comments = await Comment.find({ postId: id }).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
            res.json(comments);
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({ message: "Comments not found!" })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
```

commentModel.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    postId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Post",
    required: true,
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    replies: [{
        reply: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        commentId: {
            type: ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
    }],
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);

export default Comment;
```

Comment: When you debug, where specifically does the process first fail?  In your browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request made for the comments?  What is the server's response?

Comment: @David everything fine in backend even i can create a comment from the client side but nothing shown on the page and i can find the comment that i made in database